# differential equations for continiuos markov processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to find the forward equations for birth-and-death processes with no birth, that is, when all $\lambda$ coefficients are zero.

The forward equation for a birth-and-death process has the form:

$$P'_{i0}(s)=\mu_1P_{i1}(s)-\lambda_{0}P_{i0}(s) $$
$$P'_{ij}(s)=\lambda_{j-1}P_{ij-1}(s)+ \mu_{j+1}P_{i,j+1}(s)-(\lambda_{j}+\mu_{j})P_{ij}(s) $$

Reducing to (first line for $i=j$ and second for $j\leqslant i-1$):

$$P'_{ii}(s)=-\mu_iP_{ii}(s)$$
$$P'_{ij}(s)=\mu_{j+1}P_{i,j+1}(s)-\mu_{j}P_{ij}(s) $$

Integrating the first and using $P_{ii}(0)=1$ gives
$$P_{ii}(s)=e^{-\mu_{i}s}$$
For $j<i$ 
$$P'_{ij}(s)+\mu_{j}P_{ij}(s)=\mu_{j+1}P_{i,j+1}(s)$$
$$ e^{\mu_{j}s}[P'_{ij}(s)+\mu_{j}P_{ij}(s)]=e^{\mu_{j}s}[\mu_{j+1}P_{i,j+1}(s)] $$ (multiplied both sides by $e^{\mu_{j}s}$)
$$\frac{d}{ds}[e^{\mu_{j}s}P_{ij}(s)]=e^{\mu_{j}s}[\mu_{j+1}P_{i,j+1}(s)]$$
Since $P_{ij}(0)=0$
$$P_{ij}(s)=e^{-\mu_{j}s}*\mu_{j+1}\int_{0}^{s}e^{\mu_{j}t}P_{i,j+1}(t)dt$$
for $j<i$

But this is not sufficient as is it does not allow me to calculate the probabilities recursively.

What am I missing?

Comment: There are mistakes all over the equations in your post. You might want to revise thoroughly your question, remembering that every $P_{ij}(s)$ is a probability, hence it should be between $0$ and $1$ for every time $s$.

Comment: @Did, could you please point out one of the mistakes?

Comment: The first one is that $P_{i1}'(s)$ in the RHS of the first equation should read $P_{i1}(s)$.

Comment: Right. The next mistake is $P'_{i,j+1}(s)$ in the second equation. As I said, you might want to revise thoroughly the full text of your question.

Comment: @Did, thank you very much. I feel very embarrassed. I tried to make it neat for the people to read and wanted to use this nice formatting, but because I'm not familiar with it it was very confusing and I ended up doing a lot of copying and pasting and making these mistakes. I know it must be annoying to read someone's question when it seems like the person did not make and effort himself. This is just a tough topic for me, thus some things which are obvious for you don't stand out for me. I.e, I changed this line $P_{ii}(s)=e^{-\mu_{i}s}$, but I'm not sure why there is a minus sign.

Comment: There is a minus sign because $P'_{i,i}(s)=\mu_iP_{i,i}(s)$ DOES NOT HOLD, actually $P'_{i,i}(s)=\mu_{i+1}P_{i,i+1}(s)-\mu_iP_{i,i}(s)=-\mu_iP_{i,i}(s)$ (but I do not know what leads you to this erroneous dynamics).

Comment: @Did, ok, I redid everything on paper and I think it should be correct now after your help. Does it look right to you?

Comment: Good job. I corrected two typos and I explained what can be done using your work, as well as an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went almost as far as one can go with this approach...

Assume that all the coefficients $\mu_k$ are different (otherwise things become more complicated to write down). Starting from your recursion relations, one can guess that, for every $0\leqslant j\leqslant i$ there exists some coefficients $(\alpha_{ij}^k)_{j\leqslant k\leqslant i}$ such that, for every $s$,
$$
P_{ij}(s)=\sum_{k=j}^i\alpha_{ij}^k\mathrm e^{-\mu_ks}.
$$
To compute recursively the array $(\alpha_{ij}^k)_{0\leqslant j\leqslant k\leqslant i}$, one starts from $\alpha_{ii}^i=1$ and one computes the line $(\alpha_{ij}^k)_k$ with $j\leqslant i-1$ from the line $(\alpha_{i,j+1}^k)_k$ using the relations
$$
(\mu_j-\mu_k)\alpha_{ij}^k=\mu_{j+1}\alpha_{i,j+1}^k.
$$
This yields $\alpha_{ij}^k$ for every $k\geqslant j+1$ and one completes the line $j$ by noting that $P_{ij}(0)=0$ since $j\leqslant i-1$, hence
$$
\alpha_{ij}^j=-\sum_{k=j+1}^i\alpha_{ij}^k.
$$
Not very easy, right?

Another approach is to work with random variables. To wit, the process jumps from state $i$ to state $i-1$ after a time $T_i$ exponentially distributed with parameter $\mu_i$, hence
$$
P_{ij}(s)=P(T_{j+1:i}\leqslant s\lt T_{j:i}),\qquad T_{j:i}=\sum_{k=j}^iT_k,
$$
with the conventions that $T_{i+1:i}=0$ and $T_0=+\infty$.
Note that the random variables $T_k$ are independent hence this fully determines every $P_{ij}(s)$.

Not very explicit, eh?

So, you see, the choice is between a recursion easy to write down and not so easy to solve, and a probabilistic formulation also easy to write down but not so easy to use... Life is hard. :-)